# Is there any way to stop purged/clean assets in on demand resources in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, resources, assets, on-demand-resources

I have one big project that contains more then 22000+ images. and my ipa size is 400MB+
So I added On demand resource. it will working fine but after some time my downloaded assets purged by system...

So my question is:

1) Is any way to stop purged(cleaning) my downloaded asset which is automatic done system?

2) Is any alternate solution of on demand resource?